# Shell script calling a jenkins plug-in

Tags: jenkins, plugins

I have a deploy.sh shell script,  is it possible to execute from  a shell script and execute a jenkins plug-in using withcredentials.

I am reading all the posting but did not see a similar issue. The only way to execute is using the plug-in.  Basically only way to execute the scanner is a via a plugin

I appreciate all the help.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you trying to use a shell script to call a Jenkins plugin?

Comment: You can write pseudo-code to clarify your intent. If I understood you correctly you'll have to break the deployment script apart, but like @MB I think you should provide more details.

Comment: Sorry for vagueness. Basically I have a container image from a repository that I do a docker pull to the local jenkins worker for security scanning (qualys) and generate report.  Here are the steps and my questions.  Jenkins calls a shell script which is part of deploy.sh that will deploy the container image.  I want to perform a scan of the image before deployment.  The security tool does not have api only a jenkins plugin. My question how do I call the jenkins plugin from deploy.sh and perform the scan and exit.  Do I write groovy script, use jenkins-cli?  What the options.  Thank you